# Get PropertyGrid TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, propertygrid

How can I get PropertyGrid's TextBox from specified field?
I need this TextBox to set Pointer to the end of text.

```
var num = txtBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(Cursor.Position);
txtBox.SelectionStart = num + 1;
txtBox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

So how can I get this TextBox from PropertyGrid?
Also, property in PropertyGrid is read-only.

Comment: you need to select text in the text box?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the cursor to be located right after the last character written in the textbox, you can rely on the following code (triggered by the `TextChanged Event` of the `TextBox`):

```
private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int newX = txtBox.Location.X + TextRenderer.MeasureText(txtBox.Text, txtBox.Font).Width;
    int newY = txtBox.Bottom - txtBox.Height / 2;
    if (newX > txtBox.Location.X + txtBox.Width)
    {
        newX = txtBox.Location.X + txtBox.Width;
    }
    Cursor.Position = this.PointToScreen(new Point(newX, newY));
}
```

Bear in mind that its Y position is always in the middle.

----- UPDATE AFTER THE KINGKING COMMENT

As far as the code in the question was referred to the `TextBox`, I focused my answer on the `TextBox`. Nonetheless, KingKing is right and the `PropertyGrid` has to be brought into consideration. Below these lines I adapted the code you can find in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for `PropertyGrid`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PropertyGrid propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid();
    propertyGrid1.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
    propertyGrid1.Location = new Point(10, 20);
    propertyGrid1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
    propertyGrid1.TabIndex = 1;
    propertyGrid1.Text = "Property Grid";

    this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid1);

    propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = txtBox;
}
```

After `txtBox` is added to `propertyGrid1`, its position is updated and thus the original code can be used without any problem.

In summary, the idea is not looking for the `TextBox` inside the `PropertyGrid`, but accessing directly the `TextBox` control (which is added at runtime to the `PropertyGrid`).

Comment: How can the `OP` get access to the `txtBox`? He wants to get access to a specific textbox corresponding to a field in a `PropertyGrid`.